# How to merge NCover code coverage for 2 projects

Tags: .net, code-coverage, ncover, testautomationfx

When I run code coverage for 2 of my test projects, I get 2 zipped files and 2 html files giving me the code coverage for each of the projects. What I want is, one consolidated report that includes code coverage for both the projects. I am using ncover as the code coverage tool. Can somebody help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NCover 3, you merge coverage files using NCover.Reporting.exe, as described here:
https://www.ncover.com/support/docs/v3/ref/3-0/ncover-reporting/command-line/merging

If you have zipped files and htmls, it sounds like you're working with report, not coverage files.

Report files can't be merged, but you can merge the source (coverage) data, as described above, then generate a merged report.